# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens and i am new ussin pdo for connection to database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
    $query="INSERT INTO users (username,pwd,email) values(':userName',':pwd',':Email')";
    $stmt=$pdo->prepare($query);

    $stmt->bindParam(':userName',$username);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pwd',$password);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Email',$email);

    $stmt->execute();
```

here's my code my parameter are same but it keeps giving me this error

i have tried changing the placeholders names but did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query you have quotes around the placeholder names, making them into strings.

If you remove them it should, hopefully, work.

Like this:

```
$query="INSERT INTO users (username,pwd,email) values(:userName,:pwd,:Email)";
```

Comment: thanks for your help it did worked it was by bad thanks again